# Add Geo routing protocol

Tags: linux, ns2

I trying to add geo routing protocol in NS2 2.35,  platform(ubuntu 12.04). I have all the files related of protocol and applied all the steps to add it. But when making compilation to NS2 i get the following output:

```
 [output][1]
```

please, anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Better to post this on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: @karamalsofy, is it about this GEO https://www.math.unipd.it/~dronzani/geo.html ? ?

Answer (score 0):

> trying to add geo routing protocol in NS2.35, ... ubuntu 12.04

2014 update, ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Updated Geo patch, geo+ns2-3D_ns235.patch-3
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16a0dyDl4QGVgf4onr2KlV___HRZjagAf/view?usp=sharing

Ubuntu 12.04.5, Geo 3D

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < geo+ns2-3D_ns235.patch-3
./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
cp ns ns235-geo3D
sudo cp ns235-geo3D /usr/local/bin/
cd indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/
sudo cp setdest /usr/local/bin/setdest3D
               
          ## Simulation ##
ns235-geo3D wireless3D.tcl
```

Simulation examples, Okt 2021 update: geo3D-ex-3.tar.xz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17s3NuCnDmq7gKhPe4T1_5x5CPaJeKXML/view?usp=sharing

~3000 ns2 ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing